# Printing line that ends with a specific character

Tags: python, file

say I have a file that contains the following

```
xxx;xxx;1
xxx;xxx;1
xxx;xxx;2
xxx;xxx;2
```

I want to print only the lines that end with a 1. I have tried

```
f = open("input.txt","r")
endNum= str(raw_input("Enter the end number of a line you'd like to see: "))
for line in f:
    if line.endswith(divChoice):
        print line
```

No success with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the trailing whitespace:

```
if line.rstrip().endswith(endNum):
```

You should also use `with` to open your files and raw_input is already a str:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    endNum = raw_input("Enter the end number of a line you'd like to see: ")
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip().endswith(endNum):
            print line
```

And as @John pointed out in the comments  you should be using `.endswith(endNum)` not `.endswith(divChoice)`

You also have another issue, `"21".endswith("1")` is True but 21 is not 1, if you want to find exact matches then split and compare:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    endNum = raw_input("Enter the end number of a line you'd like to see: ")
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip().rsplit(";",1)[1] == endNum:
            print line
```

Comment: Additionally `if line.rstrip().endswith(divChoice):` should probably be `if line.rstrip().endswith(endNum):`

Comment: What if the line ends with whitespace?

Comment: @PeterWood, that is what rstrip is for?

Comment: I mean, what if removing the newline is the only problem, and the rest of the whitespace shouldn't be ignored?

Comment: if rest of the new line isn't to be ignored then use `rstrip('\n')`. But I think question is better answered with all the white spaces

Comment: @PeterWood, the OP is comparing to a number,  they would definitely not want any trailing whitespace

Answer (score 0):

First strip the line of `\n` character. `line = line.strip('\n')` then check the end. Also correct your program. You are saving user input in `endNum` but checking the end with `divChoice`.

Alternatively check `\n` also in `endswith` (not recommended)

```
if line.endswith(endNum+'\n'):
    print line
```

`+` will concatenate input with `\n` (new line character). This has a disadvantage though that the last line of the file wouldn't be accounted for (because it won't have new line character). I am producing it here just for the reference

Comment: Won't work on windows, if you're going to go that route you should use os.linesep.

Comment: If the file is opened in text mode it should be `\n`. Only binary mode retains platform specific line endings.